# QT creator does not update the .ui file and the designer

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on adding some new features on a GUI that someone previously created using `QT Creator`. First I tried editing it from the designer, but the changes I made didn't show up when I ran the project. So I added some new buttons from the `.h` file and also added some functionality to the buttons in the .cpp file and they work ok when I run the project, but the changes I made are not visible in the designer.

I tried disabling the shadow build, rebuilding all, deleting the `.cpp` and `.h` files from the `.pro` file and building again, but none of them worked.

Is there anything I can do to make the changes I made in the `.h` file visible in the designer?

> Note: I am using QT Creator 4.9.1 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt Designer is for editing the XML file (.ui) only. And only changes made to that file are visible in the Qt Designer. Adding any GUI element via code (in .cpp files) is not visible in the Qt Designer.

So why are your changes made in the Qt Designer not visible? There could be too many reasons. One of the most common which comes to my mind is having widgets being promoted in the Qt Designer. Open your .ui file and Check if the widget where you try to add something is actually a QWidget, QLabel...etc. If something is not a Qt base class, then your changes are overwritten when the .ui file is MOC'd. You can also look at the MOC file to get useful information (the automatically generated ui_something.h). Also are there multiple .ui files involved? Try adding something to them and see what happens if you run the project.

EDIT: What exactly do you mean by `changes I made in the .h file` ? If you mean the automatic generated ui_something.h it will be overwritten as soon as you build your project.

Comment: I have only one .ui file, and yes I edited the `ui_something.h` file - added some pushbuttons and a label. I created the `on_pushButton_myButton_clicked()` function under the `.cpp` file so that the label changes when I press the button for example. When I press run, the buttons are there and they function correctly, but yes when I rebuild the project they disappeared. 
I guess it does not make much sense to edit the `ui_something.h` file, so I'll make the changes from the designer and try to figure out how to build it correctly so that those changes are actually realized.